# Can I know, in a maven plugin, if a build of a module failed?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, slf4j, logback

I'm thinking of developing a maven plugin which will cause your maven build to output info messages and above if the build fails.

The context is that I'd like to configure maven to work with warn by default and disable all logs of my company (this will be done by logback configuration) and I'd like to have a plugin which talks to another in-memory logback appender to get the entire log to throw to the user in case the build fails since at that point all the data is relevant.

My question is if and how I can get that "notification" that the build failed?

For those interested my intention, which I still need to validate, is then to programmatically change the consoleAppender back to info and write everything that was accumulated to it.

I was asked about my motivations and so there are two.
The first is that I think (still crunching data to see if I'm right) that our build logs are so verbose it's effecting our build times.
The second is that some of our tests cause exceptions to be thrown as part of them which confuse the logs. I'd still like the entire log in case the build fails so that developers have all the info they need to debug their failure

Comment: The questions is why do you need such complex solution what is the exect intention or what can't you analyze in your build? BTW: which maven version do you use? How is your build running? manually?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your response. I have two motivations. The first is that I think (as still crunching data to see if I'm right) that our build logs are so verbose it's effecting our build times. The second is that some of our tests cause exceptions to be thrown as part of them which confuse the logs. I'd still like the entire log in case the build fails so that developers have all the info they need to debug their failure.

Comment: If the build logs are too verbose they become useless. If you logs are effecting your buildtimes (where i have my doubts) than you should to figure out what is really effecting your buildtime. Furthermore if tests printing exceptions etc. on console the tests must be fixed. You can of course redirect the output into a log file. I had the same in a large build. My output was ca. 100 MiB which was caused by printing everything on console debug output etc. In the meantime this has been fixed and reduced to 2 Mib which can be handled very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i don't understand your intention why not using a continious integration solution which records the whole output and can be stored for a period of time. If you need to analyze you can take a look into it. Apart from that i don't understand your need to do something what you described and what the advantage would be...

Furthermore a maven plugin will simply not work for your intention cause a maven plugin is bound to the life cycle.

If you really need something outside the mave life cycle you could take a look into the [EventSpy](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/eventspy/EventSpy.html) which could be used in the way you described, but its an extension which must be put into `lib/ext` folder of your maven installation. Best is to use the [AbstractEventSpy](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/eventspy/AbstractEventSpy.html) as parent for your own implementation.